# Ruby on Rails Update saving to wrong ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this site where a user can have many pets.  These pets are listed on there profile, and clicking on a pet takes them to that pets profile, where they have the option to edit the pet.  Loading the form for the pets works great, it gets the correct information for each one, but then there's the problem with updating.  Clicking submit on the edit form causes all updates to go to the first pet they have.  Like, if the have the pets with the IDs 2, 5 and 11, and updates on 5 or 11 go to 2.  I'm not quite sure what's going on.

Here are my edit and update actions for the PetsController:

```
#GET to /users/:user_id/pet/edit
def edit
  @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
  @pet = Pet.find_by_id( params[:id] )
end

#PUT to /users/:user_id/pet/
def update
  #Retrieve user from database
  @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
  #Retrieve user's pet
  @pet = @user.pets.find_by( params[:id] )
  #Mass assign edited pet attributes and save (update)
  if @pet.update_attributes(pet_params)
    flash[:success] = "Pet updated!"
    #Redirect user to profile page
    redirect_to user_path(id: params[:user_id] )
  else 
    render action: :edit
    Rails.logger.info(@pet.errors.messages.inspect)
  end
end
```

I've tried different ways of finding the users pet, such as

```
@user.pet(params[:id])
```

That resulted in an error of it saying it couldn't find a pet without an ID, so next I tried

```
@user.pet.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

But that resulted in update_attribute not being defined, so I assumed I shouldn't be using find_by_id anyways

Is there another way I should be doing this perhaps?  I'm thinking the error is that the pet's ID isn't being passed in correctly.  If so, what could be a fix for that?  I tried passing the ID as a hidden field from the edit form, but that didn't work.

Here's what happens in the terminal when a user tries to update a pet

```
Processing by PetsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"0tC+qRK01CMCEZWbDtJyZ4QNmXQxnaAPKT+anRKGKh5hTWekTbEHzAd+8 +YOVIWBB0/imVrMVNcpkeBR18SHNw==", "pet"=>{"color"=>"Darigan",  "species"=>"Yurble", "gender"=>"Male", "level"=>"25", "hp"=>"50",  "strength"=>"50", "defence"=>"50", "movement"=>"50", "uc"=>"1", "rw"=>"0", "rn"=>"0", "uft"=>"1", "ufa"=>"0", "description"=>"uiy7i77i7i", "id"=>"5",  "name"=>"Fouany", "hsd"=>"150"}, "user_id"=>"5"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Pet Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "pets".* FROM "pets" WHERE "pets"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
Pet Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "pets" WHERE "pets"."name" = ? AND ("pets"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "Fouany"], ["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Rendering pets/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendered pets/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (12.4ms)
Profile Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
{:name=>["has already been taken"], :color=>[], :species=>[], :gender=>[], :level=>[], :hp=>[], :strength=>[], :defence=>[], :movement=>[], :uc=>[], :rw=>[], :rn=>[], :uft=>[], :ufa=>[], :description=>[]}
Completed 200 OK in 202ms (Views: 136.1ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

As you can see, the pet's ID goes from 5 to 2 back from 5, so maybe that's somewhere to start for fixing the issue?

Any suggestions and advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hope for your sake your original code is properly indented. A lack of attention to that can make reading the flow of the code very difficult which often makes working with it frustrating.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is, I just forgot to indent it all on here.  I'll fix it now

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.pets.find_by(params[:id])
```

Should be

```
@user.pets.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: Could also be: `@user.pets.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: Tried both, @user.pets.find_by(id: params[:id]) gave me the error 
    "undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass and @user.pets.find(params[:id]) gave me "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PetsController#update
Couldn't find Pet without an ID"

Comment: but, if you have the id, is it necessary to use `@user` association with pets?, isn't `Pet.find(params[:id])` enough?

Comment: That worked, mr_suduca, except I had to change it to @pet = Pet.find(params[:pet][:id]).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your user should have only one pet (the route suggests this), then the pet id is not needed to access it. You can get the pet by

```
@user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
@pet = @user.pet
```

Have a look at this comment in your code:

```
#PUT to /users/:user_id/pet/
```

It mentions the `user_id`, but not the `id`